# Using an array of indices to access and modify arbitrarily deep nested arrays in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array of objects. Each object can also contain an array of objects, and so on to an arbitrary depth.

```
var myArray = [
    { 
        id:'foo', 
        items:[]
    },
    {
        id:'bar', 
        items:[
            {
                id:'blah'
                items:[...etc...]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I'd like to read, add, and remove objects in the nested arrays using an array of indices.

So a function to remove the value `myArray[1][3][2]` from `myArray` would be called with this array of indexes as a parameter: `[1, 3, 2]`

I've found that you can use `reduce()` to return a value like so:

```
indices.reduce((acc, cur) => Array.isArray(acc) ? acc[cur] : acc.items[cur], myArray)
```

but cannot work out how to remove or add a value using the same idea. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create a function which takes similar arguments as the [`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) function. Pass the nested array, the `indices` path, the total number of items to be deleted and collect all the new items to be added at the end using [rest parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters).

```
function deepSplice(array, indices, deleteCount, ...toBeInserted) {
  const last = indices.pop();
  const finalItems = indices.reduce((acc, i) => acc[i].items, array);
  finalItems.splice(last, deleteCount, ...toBeInserted);
  return array
}
```

- Remove the last index from the `indices` array.
- `reduce` the `indices` array to get the nested `items` array in every loop to get the final `items` array you want to do the insert/delete operation on.
- Use `splice` on the `last` index to insert/delete based on the argument passed.

If you just want to insert, pass `deleteCount = 0`. And if you just want to remove, skip the last argument.

Here's a snippet:

```js
const myArray = [
  { id: "0", items: [] },
  {
    id: "1",
    items: [
      {
        id: "1.0",
        items: [
          { id: "1.0.0", items: [] }, 
          { id: "1.0.1", items: [] }]
      },
      { id: "1.1", items: [] }
    ]
  }
];

function deepSplice(array, indices, deleteCount, ...toBeInserted) {
  const last = indices.pop();
  const finalItems = indices.reduce((acc, i) => acc[i].items, array);
  finalItems.splice(last, deleteCount, ...toBeInserted);
  return array
}

console.log(
  // removes "1.0.1" item and inserts a new object there
  deepSplice(myArray, [1,0,1], 1, { id: 'newlyInserted'})
)
```

Comment: Thanks very much. I've tested it and it works perfectly. Edit: I've updated the question with the correct plural of index.

Comment: In deepSplice, you modify `finalItems` but then return the original array. How does that work?

Comment: @SeanMC If you modify the nested object / array, the original object will also get modified because it holds a reference

Comment: Thanks I figured I just didn’t see where the reference was getting passed. Think I see it now thanks

Comment: @SeanMC every nested object is a different object. So, `const o = { a : { b: 10 } }; const nested = o.a` and if you set `nested.b = 15` And `console.log(o)` it will have the updated nested object because `o.a` is a different object in itself. In other words, the `a` property of the `o` object is assigned with an object.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to use only the indices without the last one to have it used for any operation as you want.

For deleting, you need this index to `splice` the array, and as well for updating.

In this case, you could return the parent object and use an object with `items` as property for the given array as start value for reducing.

This allows to access the parent object and use `items` for any further operation.

```
lastIndex = indices.pop();
parent = indices.reduce((r, index) => r.items[index], { items: myArray });

// further use
parent.items.splice(lastIndex, 1); // delete
```

Comment: Thank you, this answer is correct, but I have awarded the correct answer to @adiga as their answer was more detailed.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using [object-scan](https://github.com/blackflux/object-scan).

The main advantage of using object-scan is that you get more control to adjust your functions (e.g. if you wanted to get multiple entries or do fuzzy key matching etc). However there is increased complexity, so it's a trade-off and depends on your requirements.

```js
// const objectScan = require('object-scan');

const myArray = [{ id: '0', items: [] }, { id: '1', items: [ { id: '1.0', items: [{ id: '1.0.0' }, { id: '1.0.1' }] }, { id: '1.1', items: [] } ] }];

const indicesToNeedle = (indices) => indices.map((idx) => `[${idx}]`).join('.items');

const get = (array, indices) => objectScan(
  [indicesToNeedle(indices)],
  { abort: true, rtn: 'value' }
)(array);

const splice = (array, indices, deleteCount, ...toBeInserted) => objectScan(
  [indicesToNeedle(indices)],
  {
    abort: true,
    rtn: 'bool', // returns true iff spliced
    filterFn: ({ parent, property }) => {
      parent.splice(property, deleteCount, ...toBeInserted);
      return true;
    }
  }
)(array);

console.log(get(myArray, [1, 0, 1]));
// => { id: '1.0.1' }
console.log(get(myArray, [1, 0, 2]));
// => undefined

// removes "1.0.1" item and inserts two objects there
console.log(splice(myArray, [1, 0, 1], 1, { id: '1.0.1-new' }, { id: '1.0.2-new' }));
// => true
console.log(myArray);
// => [ { id: '0', items: [] }, { id: '1', items: [ { id: '1.0', items: [ { id: '1.0.0' }, { id: '1.0.1-new' }, { id: '1.0.2-new' } ] }, { id: '1.1', items: [] } ] } ]
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

```html
<script src="https://bundle.run/object-scan@13.8.0"></script>
```

*Disclaimer*: I'm the author of [object-scan](https://www.npmjs.com/package/object-scan)